# Reporting Server change needed for UK date format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

2 implementions of reporting services . One where the reporting server is on my laptop and the other where the reporting server is on a server is the only difference.

Same browser accessing reporting server url and the database being accessed is the same and its the same reports ( rdl ) being published which has the language set to EN-GB. So what when it comes to selecting the start and the end date for the report it come up with the US format and not Uk format ? So it must be a setting on the Report server that needs to be changed but what ? Help ?

Comment: Have you checked the the server's language settings as opposed to the laptop?

Comment: Both the source database for the report and the Report server database  say SELECT @@language . us_english. Oh dear . Can this be the cause ? What is the solution ?

Comment: Does this help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to set the report language value to `=User!Language`; that should pick up the language of the remote user for date formats and so on giving you a more consistent behaviour from client perspective.

Comment: Sorry that did not work for this scenario. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties window, select `Report`.

Change the language to `British English`.